# Freemarker - Loading Data to Table from a List of HashMaps?

Tags: java, freemarker

I've seen more anonymous approaches to this but let's say I have a mapping structure:

```
// FreeMarker Map
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

// Internal data
Map<String, Object> keyMap1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> keyMap2 = new HashMap<>();
List<Map<String, String>> keyList = new ArrayList<>();


keyMap1.put("k1", "val1");
keyMap1.put("k2", "val2");
keyMap2.put("k1", "val3");
keyMap2.put("k2", "val4");

keyList.add(keyMap1);
keyList.add(keyMap2);

map.put("1", "value");
map.put("nestedMap", keyList);
```

With a Freemarker template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>${1}</div>
    <#list nestedMap as hashMap>
        <div>
            ${hashMap[k1]}
            ${hashMap[k2]}
        </div>
    </#list>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the goal outcome:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>value</div>
        <div>
            val1
            val2
        </div>
        <div>
            val3
            val4
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a possible way of doing this where you can access the values of a list of nested maps?

Comment: You aren't sharing any error message. But for example, it should be like `hashMap.k1`, (or `hashMap["k1"]`). `hashMap[k1]` means that the key is stored in variable `k1`, which is not what you meant.

Comment: Sorry meant to close this. Accessing by .k1 worked fine.